# Check with php if two phrases contain the same word

Tags: php, mysql, text

I want to check if two Phrase contain **same word** with PHP I'm using **strpos and strstr** but is not working for me because I don't know exactly the position of the word.

```
example :

Thismyfirstword
checkfirstmore
```

In two words, there exists a word  '**first**' that means it is true .

do you have any idea?

**More Explain**

i have two **table** and i well make loup to check if a phrases contain the same word like this :

1. **Table one containe :**

   wordone - thatistrue- youknowho- mynamesis - moreexmple - Thismyfirstword
2. **Table two containe :**

nothinghere - checkfirstmore - thatwatineed -moremore- younameslike

**Result**

Thismyfirstword = checkfirstmore (**first**)
**and**

mynamesis = younameslike  (**names**)

moreexmple = moremore (**more**)

Comment: How will you identify first is a word from two strings? I mean is there any specific provision?

Comment: Your question is not clear, can you share you attempt and required output ?

Comment: ok i will explain right now thanks

Comment: Hello i'm explain more check the question please
No is no minimum length the table generer automatique

Comment: what about `moreexmple` and `moremore` ?

Comment: @user2486 yes and moreexmple  = moremore  (more) every world like auther world

Comment: @Siraj so we can specific to 3 word

Comment: @Siraj yes we can add minimum word length as 3 because i don't find any solution , so what method we can use ?

Comment: which database are you using ?

Comment: @Ravi mysql but i have two requete every requete added to table

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for. It will return "TRUE" if both have some common word of minimum length **3** as you mentioned in the comment.

```
    $str1 = "Crazyworld";
    $str2 = "Helloworld";
    echo "This is ".check($str1, $str2);
    function check($string1, $string2)
    {
        for($i = 0; $i <= strlen($string1) - 3;  $i++)
        {
            $sub = substr($string1, $i, 3);
            if(strpos($string2, $sub) !== false){
                return "TRUE";
            }
        }
        return "FALSE";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
strpos($string1, 'first');
```

if it returns 0 or greater than 0 then it means word match.

else, not matched

```
if(strpos($string1, 'first') > -1){
    echo "Found";
}else{
    echo "Not Found";
}
```

So you can check for string2 too.

Comment: i don't know the word first that is the problem i have two table and i need to make this test

Comment: Question is not clear because how can one knew about these two string from `Thismyfirstword
checkfirstmore`

Comment: Convert both strings to an array. Use array_intersect for the 2 arrays, if you get the result, means you have something in common, else not.

Comment: Well, here we can give hints rest he can optimize as per his need.

Comment: Hello i'm explain more check the question please